# Why are slow jQuery animations choppy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I'm having a hard time googling this issue because most of the things I can find are about animations that are supposed to be fast but are acting slow. My question is regarding an animation that I want to have a long duration but still be smooth.

I've created this jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/93Bqx/

I'm trying to make an element slowly move to another position over time. But the animation is very choppy.

Basically, it boils down to something like this:

```
$elem.animate({
        left: x,
        top: y
}, someLargeNumber);
```

I'm wondering if the problem is that the animation is so slow that each step is less than a pixel and so it is rounding them to either 0 or 1 making it appear to drop frames and then move all at once. But I don't know how I would check or fix this.

Is there a better way to be doing slow animations so they're smooth? I had a similar one created with CSS3 and translate(x,y) that was smooth but unfortunately I need more flexibility than I think I can get with CSS.

Comment: good read on the topic: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Comment: @Yoshi thank you! Exactly what I was interested in learning about. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not much smoother even using a CSS transition.

I added the [Transit jQuery plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) to test a CSS transition instead, and it looks almost the same.

Your code with minor fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/93Bqx/5/

Same code but with Transit added: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/93Bqx/6/.

I think this is a limitation of the fact that (most?) browsers don't do subpixel rendering. As you mentioned, the `x` and `y` of the element is rounded after every step of the animation, and it's this rounding that causes the unsightly "jiggling" effect.

The CSS transition version does look noticeably better for less pathological test cases. Read this for more information: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Comment: I had never heard of this; I'll have to look into this plugin. Thanks for the suggestion! I looked at the docs and changed it from animating the top and bottom properties directly to using its native x/y and it is a lot smoother (but oddly a bit wobbly) http://jsfiddle.net/XSEd8/

Comment: Update: I have this working now in my actual code and it's great. +1 for jquery.transit. Only problem I ran into was there not being a way to stop transitions but I found [a fork of the codebase](https://github.com/tblasv/jquery.transit) that adds that feature.

Comment: Good to know. I think that, roughly, the slower the computer is, the more of an improvement the CSS transition version will provide. Also, I don't think you should accept my answer (if you were planning to) just yet. Give it a bit more time and see if a better answer arrives.

Comment: I'm hoping @Yoshi makes an answer based on his comment to my original post. It actually explains the "why" of this (positioning by `top` and `left` can't do subpixel rendering whereas `translate` can).

Answer (score 7):

I guess it's the inevitable bargain with doing animation programmatically.
Maybe try a framework specialized in animation like:

http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/

but adapting the animation to CSS would be best.

Comment: Yep, here's a fork that uses GreenSock's GSAP with transforms instead of top/left: http://jsfiddle.net/2LpgY/1/ It's much smoother in webkit, but Firefox uses a different antialiasing technique which doesn't seem to accommodate sub-pixel rendering. So thirtydot is right about it being a browser thing in some cases. I'd also argue that CSS animations wouldn't be better, especially if you need tight control - see http://www.greensock.com/why-gsap/

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with how often you move an element. For example, if you move the object once every second, it will seem choppy. Try decreasing the amount of time between each move as well as decreasing the distance between each move. See http://jsfiddle.net/2K9xP/ for an example.

So we have...

```
var duration = Math.round(10 * distance);
```

instead of...

```
var duration = Math.round(1000 * distance);
```

Comment: The point is that the object moves slowly. That box zooms around like it's on ecstasy.

Comment: It's more to demonstrate the fact that it can move seamlessly if the amount it moves per frame is a high enough value. Moving an object 1 pixel every second will seem choppy because our eyes see more detail (something to do with framerates I guess).

Comment: Also if we have higher resolution displays which could cater for more accurate positions, this would make slower animations see more seamless I think.