# Why is animation jittery/choppy at long duration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, velocity.js

When I animate a box just 90px to left and 90px down in 15 seconds using velocity.js, the animation is a bit jittery.

How can I fix this problem, or should I just use another animation library for JS?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#box").velocity({
    top: 90,
    left: 90
  }, {
    duration: 15000,
    easing: 'ease-in-out'
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//julian.com/research/velocity/build/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="//julian.com/research/velocity/build/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">box</div>
```

[View on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEMmmL)

Comment: I think you may mean "jittery". It seems that there is not enough resolution to make the animation any more smooth at that speed. When moving one pixel a second, you can see the box jump.

Comment: Yes, I mean jittery. Can I fix this jittering?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are slow jQuery animations choppy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996519/why-are-slow-jquery-animations-choppy)

Comment: @showdev it's not exactly what I meant, but I saw translateY. And that did the trick! Thank you!!

Comment: Oh, cool. Wow, that does seem to help. You might consider posting an answer to your own question, with an example of how you fixed the problem, so that future coders can benefit from your solution.

Comment: For further reference, see related articles by [Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) and [Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/tale-of-animation-performance/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @showdev, replacing left and top with translateX and translateY did the trick.

Code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#box").velocity({
    translateY: 90,
    translateX: 90
  }, {
    duration: 15000,
    easing: 'ease-in-out'
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//julian.com/research/velocity/build/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="//julian.com/research/velocity/build/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">box</div>
```

[View on Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEMmmL)