# Jquery jerky slideDown on edge and IE but not on JS fiddle?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, microsoft-edge, slidedown, velocity.js

I spent my whole day on this problem and I have no more hair on my head.

**Introduction :**

You will need Microsoft Edge or IE to test this as the bug is only visible on these browsers.

This is a simple code where I'm making a slide down on a hidden div triggered when the user is pushing a button.

**what is the problem :**

The slideDown is Jerky on edge and IE on the net. You can check out my temporary code on [www.doctirank.com](http://www.doctirank.com). This is smooth on chrome, on firefox not as smooth, and terrible on IE and Edge. But when I copy the exact same code on [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ocfv4gL/5/), the problem does not show up  ?!

**More info :**

here is the code when pushing the button defined by the id "toggler" : note that I'm using .velocity() instead of .animate() because jerky animations has been reported by using .animate(). So this lead is already eliminated. After the end of the animation, a modal pops up.

```
$('#toggler').click(function () {

    $("#toggle").delay(800).velocity("slideDown", {
        duration: 1200
    });
    $("#pipi").delay(800).velocity("scroll", {
        duration: 1200
    });

    var supa = document.getElementById('car');
    supa.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function (event) {
        $('#myModal').modal();

    }, false);

    return false;
});
```

Do you have any solution to this ? I need my hairs back.

Comment: Have you seen this answer to [Why is animation jittery/choppy at long duration?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35071630/3585500)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm afraid it does not solve my problem.